# Evaluating a integral C where C is a curve (MultiVar)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the $\int_C \sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2}$where C is the curve x = 2y = 3z from z = 1 to z = 3

So far I have tried converting all of the variables into Z's and I got $9z^2+\frac{9}{4}z^2 + z^2$ and integrated it from 1 to 3. But I am not sure if that is the correct way of attemping this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parametrize the curve $C$ with $\vec{r}(t)$:
   $$
   \begin{cases}
   x=t\\
   y=\frac{t}{2}\\
   z=\frac{t}{3}
   \end{cases}
   $$
   with $t\in [3,9]$. Note that $||\vec{r}'(t)||=\frac{7}{6}$.
2. Rewrite the integral in terms of $t$ and compute:
   $$
   \int_C \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \; ds = \int_3^9 \frac{7}{6}\sqrt{t^2+\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{t^2}{9}}\; dt = 49
   $$

Comment: Where did the 7/6 come from? Im trying to put it together the rest looks right.

Comment: $\int_C f(x,y,z)\; ds = \int_t f(t) ||\vec{r}'(t) || dt$, and $ ||\vec{r}'(t) || =7/6$.